# Copying a worksheet with OpenPyXL doesn't keep data validations

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsx

Data validations don't seem to be kept when I'm trying to copy an existing worksheet to create a new one with the `Workbook.copy_worksheet()` method.

With a simple example :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='BRI.xlsx')
templateSheet = wb["1"]
print(templateSheet.data_validations)
newSheet = wb.copy_worksheet(templateSheet)
print(newSheet.data_validations)
```

I get this :

```
Parameters:
disablePrompts=None, xWindow=None, yWindow=None, count=5, dataValidation=[<openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation.DataValidation object>
Parameters:
sqref=<MultiCellRange [B158:H163 B147:H156 B132:H145 B126:H127 B129:H130]>, showErrorMessage=True, showDropDown=None, showInputMessage=True, allowBlank=False, errorTitle=None, error=None, promptTitle=None, prompt=None, type='list', errorStyle=None, imeMode=None, operator=None, formula1='TEST1', formula2=None, <openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation.DataValidation object>
Parameters:
sqref=<MultiCellRange [B25:H68 B87:H108 B120:H123 B110:H113 B115:H118 B70:H85]>, showErrorMessage=True, showDropDown=None, showInputMessage=True, allowBlank=False, errorTitle=None, error=None, promptTitle=None, prompt=None, type='list', errorStyle=None, imeMode=None, operator=None, formula1='TEST2', formula2=None, <openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation.DataValidation object>
Parameters:
sqref=<MultiCellRange [B18:H23]>, showErrorMessage=True, showDropDown=None, showInputMessage=True, allowBlank=False, errorTitle=None, error=None, promptTitle=None, prompt=None, type='list', errorStyle=None, imeMode=None, operator=None, formula1='TEST3', formula2=None, <openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation.DataValidation object>
Parameters:
sqref=<MultiCellRange [B5:H16]>, showErrorMessage=True, showDropDown=None, showInputMessage=True, allowBlank=False, errorTitle=None, error=None, promptTitle=None, prompt=None, type='list', errorStyle=None, imeMode=None, operator=None, formula1='TEST4', formula2=None, <openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation.DataValidation object>
Parameters:
sqref=<MultiCellRange [B165:H172]>, showErrorMessage=True, showDropDown=None, showInputMessage=True, allowBlank=False, errorTitle=None, error=None, promptTitle=None, prompt=None, type='list', errorStyle=None, imeMode=None, operator=None, formula1='TEST5', formula2=None]
<openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation.DataValidationList object>
Parameters:
disablePrompts=None, xWindow=None, yWindow=None, count=0, dataValidation=[]
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Openpyxl only copies cells between worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the validations to the new sheet yourself like so

```
from copy import copy

for validation in templateSheet.data_validations.dataValidation:
    newSheet.add_data_validation(copy(validation))
```